# How make the subdomains be listed underneath your domain name in search results?

Tags: web, seo, search-engine, subdomain

I have been looking to a notable number of famous websites and i noticed that some of those top ones are displaying their sub-domains down below their domain name in the first entry of the search results. How do they accomplish this? Is this a SEO technique that they use? or Google automatically adds those for famous top websites?

Here is a picture below illustrating what i mean:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those links are called "sitelinks" I dont believe this is anything you set up yourself. If the domain is trusted google determines what the important topics to put there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's what i was thinking of as well. That Google as a search engine does that automatically for top trusted websites.